# Grep the entire text after a certain word using grep/awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

We use Hashicorp vault to store certs and keys.
I want to retrieve the certs/keys stored in vault.
With vault API command, I get below output

```
vault get /mysecret.key
output:
====== Data ======
Key         Value
---         -----
password    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Expected output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Tried:

```
vault get /mysecret.key | sed -n '/^password/,$p'

password    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How do I use grep/awk/sed to get the expected output?

Comment: You could issue vault command to query specific field. `vault kv get -field=password /mysecret.key` or a similar command. Don't remember the exact command now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following code.

```
your_API_command | 
awk -v RS= 'match($0,/-+BEGIN.*END RSA PRIVATE KEY-+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, run your API command and send its output as an standard input to `awk` command. Where using nullify RS then using `match` function to match string from `-`(1 or more occurrences) followed by `BEGIN` till string `END RSA PRIVATE KEY` followed by 1 or more occurrences of `-`.

***2nd solution:*** A little tweaked form of 1st solution here, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
your_API_command | awk -v RS='-+BEGIN.*END RSA PRIVATE KEY-+' 'RT{print RT}'
```

Comment: With that data you could just: `awk -v RS= 'match($0,/-+BEGIN/){print substr($0,RSTART)}'` but I guess it's good to match the end as well.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for the answer. Used the similar query for other files too. When saving this output to a variable like echo Key=$(API | awk ...), I lose the format and it prints as a string. Is there a way to retain the format when you use variable?

Comment: @ERR, to save it into a variable use something like: `var=$(API | awk -v RS= 'match($0,/-+BEGIN.*END RSA PRIVATE KEY-+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
)` once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: It prints the output like this, as a single line value -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----xxxxxxyyyyyyy-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: @ERR, print it like: `echo "$var"` use `"` while printing values to keep new lines in variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
vault get /mysecret.key | sed -n '/^password[[:blank:]]*/,$ {s///; p;}'

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Command Details:**

- `-n`: Disable normal printing
- `/^password[[:blank:]]*/,$`: Pattern match start from `password` followed by 0 or whitespaces till end of file
- `{s///; p;}`: For matching block do a substitute by removing `password` followed by 0+ whitespace from output and using `p` just print it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ vault get /mysecret.key | awk 'sub(/^password[[:space:]]*/,""){f=1} f'
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/.*\npassword\s*//' file
```